# Remove single cell from a matrix

Tags: matrix, na

I am trying to remove single cells which are NA from a matrix data. I need to keep all of the other data in the matrix. All I could do is removing all the rows and colomns if a single cell is NA.

#First I replaced all the data points that are higher than 600,000

adjusted_data<-apply(data, c(1,2), FUN = function(x){ ifelse (x > 600,000, NA, x) })

#now I need to remove these single cells which turned to NA.

adjusted_data<- na.omit(adjusted_data)

However, When I use this code, all the ROWs and COLUMNS are removed even if a single cell is NA.

Comment: what does it mean to 'remove' a cell (also, what langauge)

Comment: Maybe you just want to replace your NAs by zeros?

Comment: I need to do it in R, and want to omit all the single cells that has NA. 
I can not replace them by 0, because I need mean values at the end. 

#First I replaced all the data points that are higher than 600,000
adjusted_data<-apply(data, c(1,2), FUN = function(x){
  ifelse(x > 600,000, NA, x)
})
adjusted_data<- na.omit(adjusted_data) 

When I use this code, all the ROWs and COLUMNS are removed even if a single cell is NA.